# Phonegap/Cordova APP name i18n support in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using phonegap,It's easy to get app name i18n done with Android by

```
res/values-zh-rcn  
res/values-en-rus

android:label="@string/app_name"(AndroidManifest.xml)
```

but how about iOS?